# How does <awaitable> object in Python work?

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, coroutine

Let's say we have 2 coroutines.
I write `await <awaitable>` in first one. In this line the context of coroutine switches and other coroutine runs. `<awaitable>` is a function that can be used in await expression. I want to know a little bit more about `<awaitable>`.

After we switch context back to first coroutine, we will already have result of `<awaitable>`. Program is not parallel, if interpreter executes first coroutine then how do we wait for `<awaitable>`?

Thank you for any explanations!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but let me ask: If you had 2 plain functions `f1` and `f2`, and you call `f1` in the body of `f2`: who controls the `f1` execution and return value? Only after putting the coroutines as tasks on the event loop will you get another sort of outside control (which depends also on the structure of the coroutines).